# How to create Gloabal Variable inside a function in solidity?

Tags: solidity

How can I create a global variable inside a function every time it's called? For example:

I would like to create a new chainlink price feed for every tokne added to the contract I tried to do it like this:

```
function addAllowedToken(string memory _priceFeedName, address _token, address _priceFeedAddress) external onlyOwner {
    allowedTokens.push(_token);
    AggregatorV3Interface _priceFeedName = new AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeedAddress);

}
```

It is not compiling probably because it's since I don't know how to do it any other way.

Is it even possible?

I would then like to access the price feed in other functions so it has to be global.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. It would also be bad practice to do so.

What i suggest is creating a mapping and probably use a struct in there. Its hard to figure out what you exactly need with the information given.

The mapping and struct could look like this:

```
  mapping(uint => myStruct) private )myMapping;
  
  struct myStruct ( 
    address priceFeedAddress;
    //etc
  );
```

You could for example make the key of your mapping the tokenaddresses or a tokenId. And then add all the information you want to save for each function call in the struct and add that to the value of the key. This way you can store data you want/need.

Comment: Thanks! I think I figured out how to do it. If it is correct I will add it to this question later.